# Defining Infix Operators in Mathjs

Tags: javascript, function, infix-operator, mathjs

I want to be able to write a J-like language using the mathjs `math.parser()` function result.

Let's say I want to define an operator `#` that returns the length of an array. Ideally it would work like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
#a             // yields 3
```

Then, for fun, an operator `$` that takes two arrays and combines them.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [4, 5, 6]
a $ b            // yields [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

How might I do these things with mathjs? If I cannot do them, what tool might I use instead?

### Why it's different

I want to be able to use it like this:

```
var parser = math.parser();
parser.eval("a = [1,2,3]; #a");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I extend the JavaScript language to support a new operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762338/how-would-i-extend-the-javascript-language-to-support-a-new-operator)

Comment: @Vihan It's sort of related, but I specifically want to use them in the `parser#eval` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression parser of math.js doesn't support adding custom operators, so you will have to clone the project and adjust the code of the parser for that:

https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/src/expression/parse.js

Note that right now the `#` character is used as start of a comment in the parser.

If you want to create your own parser for your own specific syntax, you could do so using a parser generator like [jison](http://zaa.ch/jison/) or [peg](http://pegjs.org/).

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll accept, but still leave the bounty up until later.

Comment: I just now realize that you made/maintain mathjs o_O Thanks for showing me peg and jison, they are perfect tools for the job at hand.