# How to add a custom operator to Javascript or node.js with BabelJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, esprima, escodegen

I would like to add custom operators, keywords, and syntax to Javascript.

Someone asked for help with this many years ago and got some great instructions:

[How would I extend the JavaScript language to support a new operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762338/how-would-i-extend-the-javascript-language-to-support-a-new-operator/20764137#20764137)

Implemented here:

https://github.com/IonicaBizau/js-custom-operators

This method does not work with the most current version of `esprima.js`.

Is this possible with `babel.js`?