# Javascript defining arrows

Tags: javascript, function

Please help me edit the title.

Basically, what I mean by 'defining arrows' is making "->" have a function.

For example, let say I give "->" a function:

```
console.log("Hello")
```

So, when I use this:

```
->
```

Javascript will automatically do 'console.log("Hello")'.

I tried this method but failed to work:

```
function ->{
    console.log("Hello")
}
```

My question is, is there a method for what I want? Why or why not?

Comment: You cannot have a function name starting with `-`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Please put it as an answer. Basically, I hope this will help someone else when they come here.

Comment: this is basically a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728460/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-operators-in-javascript

Comment: @Vicky sorry, basically I dont even know what to search.

Comment: @leonneo no harm meant bro ..... just pointed you out in the right direction ...... that post will help you out if u check it xD

Comment: @leonneo You might want to see this Wikipedia article: [Operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. `->` is not a valid identifier, and you can't define custom operators in JavaScript (if that's what you were going for). From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables):

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>
> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.

Of course, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to define members on objects that are not valid identifiers, like this:

```
window['->'] = function() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

But then you would have to call with this rather unwieldy syntax:

```
window['->']();
```

Comment: So, for the window[] function, can you remove the parenthesis?

Comment: @leonneo no, `window` is basically an object that represents the global context inside a browser (e.g. `alert` is actually `window.alert`) and the brackets (`[…]`) are used to access a member of that object by specifying its name as a string (which works even if the name isn't a valid identifier). And no, you can't remove the parentheses; `window['->']` is a reference to the function, putting the parentheses at the end is what invokes the function.

Comment: Then is there a way to insert 2 functions in one window tag like this:
window["-> <-"]

Comment: @leonneo No. The string will be used to access a property of the window object. `window['-> <-']` will return the property of `window` with the name `'-> <-'` if one exists, or `undefined` if one does not exist.