# Is there a way to add operators to AngularJS expression?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to add beginsWith (^=) and endsWith ($=).

E.g., `scope.$eval('"abcd" ^= "a"')` should return 'true'

Comment: Just write a function to do that and call the function.  [Javascript does not allow custom operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728460/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-operators-in-javascript/20728490#20728490).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Angular's documentation on expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), you should use controller\filter:

> **No function declarations or RegExp creation with literal notation**
>
> You can't declare functions or create regular expressions from within
>   AngularJS expressions. This is to avoid complex model transformation
>   logic inside templates. Such logic is better placed in a controller or
>   in a dedicated filter where it can be tested properly.

Comment: thanks. It seems that AngularJS expressions are not open for such extensions.