# Perform math operation on two Objects in Javascript without selecting the detailed keys

Tags: javascript

I have two objects, as below:

```js
var origin = {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
}

var coordinates = {
    x: 5,
    y: 5
}
```

I calculate the delta as follows:

```
var delta = {
    x : origin.x - coordinates.x,
    y : origin.y - coordinates.y
}
```

This works, BUT I am looking for a more elegant way, given all I really do is **origin - coordinates**. Unfortunately, **origin - coordinates** is not valid javascript

Any suggestions? Maybe using a `...` spread operator?

Comment: Do you just have two objects or Array of objects ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create custom operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728460/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-operators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic answer is: No, there isn't a way to do that which is likely to pass your "elegance" test. :-) (I like [Sairyu's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70064153/157247) of creating a reusable function [perhaps with a shorter name]. Or you might even make it a `Point` class with `add`, `sub`, etc.)

"Elegant" is a value judgement, but if these are the only properties in the objects  and you want to avoid explicitly writing `x` and `y`, you can use a `for..in` loop, a `for..of` loop on `Object.keys`, or a combination of `Object.entries`, `map`, and `Object.fromEntries` though the overhead on that last one starts looking a bit overkill.

```
const delta = {};
for (const key in origin) {
    delta[key] = origin[key] - coordinates[key];
}
```

or

```
const delta = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(origin)) {
    delta[key] = origin[key] - coordinates[key];
}
```

or

```
const delta = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(origin).map(
        ([key, value]) => [key, value - coordinates[key]]
    )
);
```

But again: None of these is likely to be "elegant" by most definitions I can imagine. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the best way is by making a function, something like this :

```
function calculate_coordinates(point1, point2) {
    const x = point1.x - point2.x;
    const y = point1.y - point2.y;
    return {x, y};
}
```

Comment: This is probably the only thing that really qualifies as "elegant." :-) But note that your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), you need to declare `x` and `y`. (Also, you can use shorthand property notation in the return: `return {x, y}`.)

Comment: It could even be a class with `sub`, `add`, etc.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the declarations (and using shorthand notation).

Comment: I'll put that in mind, thank you.